# How to open a port for http traffic on ec2 from node app?

Tags: node.js, linux, apache, amazon-ec2, devops

So I have an ec2 instance running a node app on port 3000, very typical setup. However I now need to run additional apps on this server, which currently are running on their own servers, also on port 3000. So I need to migrate them all to one server, and presumably run them on different ports.

So if I want to run node apps and have them on 3000, 3010, 3020, etc, how do I do this the right way?

Comment: simply change the port that each node listens. Any problem with that?

Comment: @AmiramKorach The connection times out when I try to view it in a browser. Eg `www.myurl.com:3010`

Comment: can you do it locally on the server?

Comment: @AmiramKorach What do you mean?

Comment: ssh to server. try `curl http://localhost:3010` what do you get?

Comment: @AmiramKorach I get an HTML document, as expected.

Comment: You'll be able to get response by req from localhost, but timeout through internet gateway, cause you havent authorized inbound traffic to those ports in your security group, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to authorize inbound traffic to your ec2 instance via AWS Console, or API. Here is a good description how to do that :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Since authorizing is normally a one off, probably better to do it through the AWS Console, however, if one of your requirements is to spin up node apps in different ports in an automated fashion, then you'll probably want to look at this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#authorizeSecurityGroupIngress-property